# How do you fail a unittest in python if an error message does not pop up on the tested webpage when it should?

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing, webdriver

I am trying to write a python selenium unittest for a login page. When no username or password is entered before clicking the login button, an error message should pop up telling the user that a username and password is required. However, no error message is displayed on the webpage when you do this so the test should fail. How do I write a test that takes this into account?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably check the size/length/value of the username and password.
If empty then fail the test else pass.

An example would be look like this:

```py
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="locator"]').get_attribute('value')
if len(element) == 0:
    # your actions here
```